# Copy assets to CDN then delete old versions

Tags: laravel

What I would like to do during deployment

- Assets are compiled to the `public` disk (done)
- Assets are uploaded to a temp directly on S3 storage (done)
- Various checks to make sure that all the files are uploaded (done)
- Switch over the live and temp directory (this question)

So I have an S3 storage where there are two folders `prod` and `prod-temp`.

They contain the exact same files, but `prod-temp` has newer versions (just uploaded).

What I'd like to do is make sure that the latest uploaded files end up in the `prod` folder. The reason that I first upload them to `prod-temp` is to make sure that the uploading first happens successfully.

I apparently I can not use `renameDirectory` with the `Storage` facade, else that would probably be the best approach: delete the `prod` folder then rename the `prod-temp` folder to `prod`. `Storage::move` also doesn't seem to work on folders, only on files.

Below the code that works, but the downside is that this will take about 5 seconds to execute, which is too much downtime.

```php
$cdn->Storage::disk('s3');

$dir_final = 'prod';
$dir_temp = 'prod-temp';

// Note that file['name'] contains the full filename + extension

foreach($files as $file) {
  $cdn->delete($dir_final.'/'.$file['name']);
  $cdn->move($dir_temp.'/'.$file['name'], $dir_final.'/'.$file['name']);
}
```

If I use `$cdn->copy` instead of `$cdn-move` it's faster (2.5 seconds) but it still feels that there could be a better approach.

Is it possible to rename the folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 doesn't allow to rename folders/directories even from their console. Because in S3 directories aren't a first class citizen i.e to say they store everything as key => value pairs in objects.

In your case I guess the best possible option in terms of performance would be to:

- Copy all files from `prod-tmp` to `prod` (Copy should overwrite the old files with same name)

  - If somehow overwrite doesn't work - Delete `prod` directory and create `prod` directory again (see if `cleanDirectory` works) and then copy the files
- Delete `prod-tmp` directory

```php
$cdn = Storage::disk('s3');
$finalDir = 'prod';
$tmpDir = 'prod-tmp';

//If overwrite doesn't work
//$cdn->deleteDirectory($finalDir);
//$cdn->makeDirectory($finalDir);

//...
foreach($files as $file) {
    $cdn->copy($tmpDir . '/' . $file['name'], $finalDir . '/' . $file['name']);
}

$cdn->deleteDirectory($tmpDir);
```

Below doesn't work with s3 and probably any object storage where everything is stored as key=>value pairs and directories aren't first class citizen.

Guess you can try to delete the `prod` directory first and then use `move` to rename the `prod-tmp` directory

```php
Storage::disk('s3')->deleteDirectory('prod');

Storage::disk('s3')->move('prod-tmp', 'prod');
```

Haven't tested but should work - just be careful to have a backup of the data to be on a safer side.

Comment: I should have noted this in the question: I tried that but it doesn't work. Apparently you can not use `move` to rename directories, only files.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Cause it works on local and public (local) disk.

Comment: Yeah, but let me test again to be sure :-)

Comment: No, doesn't work. Also doesn't work with a trailing slash.

Comment: Guess it must be unique with the S3 Adapter then. Will check and let you know if I can find a workaround

Comment: That's probably the case yes. Thanks for checking!

Comment: @eskimo Have updated answer as per my findings & understanding, see if it works with regards to performance for you

Comment: `copy` doesn't work: you apparently can not overwrite files. `cleanDirectory` also doesn't work (not available for `Storage` facade). So I can either do `deleteDirectory` and then directly after do `deleteDirectory` for the `prod` directory as you indicated, or keep the code in my original answer. The performance difference is negligible.

Comment: Read `copy` and `move` will overwrite target location in the docs https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/v2/docs/usage/filesystem-api/  - **Moving & Copying**  - don't know why it doesn't work with s3